# Morse functions with minimal number critical points

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

Is it true that $RP^n$ has a Morse function with n critical points,and dont have Morse function with n-1 critical points

Answer (score 3):

Your  first question: no.  A Morse function on $RP^1 \cong S^1$ has at least two critical points (a maximum and minimum).

More generally, the Morse inequalities tell us that the number of critical points of index $k$ of a Morse function is bounded below by the rank of the $k$th homology group of the space in any field.  For $RP^n$, we look at $H_k(RP^n, \mathbb{Z}/2)$, $0 \leq k \leq n$, and see that a Morse function on $RP^n$ must have at least $n+1$ critical points.

Comment: And there are indeed Morse functions with $n+1$ critical points, e.g. $\mathbb{RP}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,[x_0\colon\dotsc x_n]\mapsto\sum_{i=0}^njx_j^2/\sum_{i=0}^nx_j^2$, so this is the minimal amount.