Find the minimum number of critical points of a Morse function $f: \mathbb R P^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$
This question is from an old publicly available qualifying exam that I’m using to learn this field (Stanford geometry and topology). I've read Milnor's book in the past and used it to solve another practice problem, but this attempted solution was done visually in my head as I was driving across the country. I don't recall Milnor having an example like this in his book, but I could be wrong. All work is my own.


Find the minimum number of critical points of a Morse function $f: \mathbb R P^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$

Answer: The strategy here is to consider how $\mathbb R P^n$ can be constructed: Take the hemisphere $H^n \subseteq S^n$ and perform the identification $s \sim (-s)$ on the antipodal points of $\partial H^n = S^{n-1}$. We'll first determine the number of critical points required by this boundary identification, and then solve for the critical points on the interior of $H^n$.
Now, consider any point $s \in S^{n-1}$. We can choose exactly $n-1$ great circles that span $S^{n-1}$ and connect $s$ with $-s$. Have $\{ c_i\}$ be this collection of great circles. We don't want $f$ to be constant in a neighborhood of $s$, else there would be infinitely many degenerate critical points. Then we'll have $f$ increase/decrease clockwise along each great circle as it departs from $s$. However, for our identification to work, we'll need to have $f$ obtain the same value at $f(-s) = f(s)$.
Then at some point along each great circle, $f$ must switch from increasing/decreasing to decreasing/increasing. From Rolle's theorem and the antipodal symmetry, this implies that there are exactly two additional critical points for each great circle $c_i$. Due to the antipodal symmetry, $f$ must also be decreasing/increasing along each great circle as it approaches $s$, and increasing/decreasing as it departs $-s$. This implies that $s$ and $-s$ are critical points too.
Before performing our identification we have $2 + 2 \text{(number of $c_i$)} = 2 + 2(n-1) = 2n$ critical points. Since these critical points on the boundary are really identified down into one, we have $2n/2 = n$ critical points from the boundary identification.
Denote the interior of $H^n$ by $\underline{H}^n$. Pre-identification, there needs to be an arc that passes between $s$ and $-s$. We have $n$ critical points that are identified, so there may be $n$ additional arcs that induce $n$ additional critical points in $\underline H ^n$. However, unlike the case at the boundary, we can make all of these arcs intersect at a single point (the "pole" of $\underline  H^n$). This allows us to only require one additional critical point. Then for each $\mathbb RP^n$, the minimum required number of critical points is $\boxed{n+1}$.

(a) Is $n+1$ the correct number of critical points for each $\mathbb R P^n$?
As a bonus, if there's some faster power tool, theorem, or method (perhaps analytical, like a link between Betti numbers/homology groups and critical points of a Morse function), then I'd appreciate this, because solving this problem using visualizations and projections for the higher dimensional cases was difficult and took me a while to think through.

Your final answer seems to be correct, and one bound can be derived from the Morse inequalities and the other by exhibiting an explicit Morse function.  However, I don't understand your approach.  For instance, you begin by assuming that $s$ is any point on the "boundary", and then you purport to show that $s$ is a critical point, which formally means that every point is a critical point.   In general, it seems difficult to separate the count of critical points into counts on $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ and $\mathbb{R}P^n \setminus \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$.

See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4620373/276134
